# php returns null in a value iam sure i have something in it?

Tags: php, android

here's my php code

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "database");

    $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    $response = array();
if($Tag === "panic"){
$username = $_POST["username"];  
$user_record = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");          
$value = mysql_fetch_array($user_record);
$userlocation = $value['location'];
$response["userlocation"] = $userlocation;
echo json_encode($response)
}
?>
```

where should this echo (echo json_encode($response)) appear?! cause when i run this i get a blank page! and also in android when i receive it, it's null?! and there is a value in my users table where username equals the username i sent from android?! so why does it return me a null value?!

Comment: First of all you are missing a semicolon here.. `echo json_encode($response);` <----

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is all your code (otherwise it would be weird and we couldn't say a thing about it :) ), you do this

```
if($Tag === "panic"){
```

but that is never true, as `$Tag` is never set. So you don't "enter" your if. For testing, change it to

```
if(true)
```

and you'll at least get some result.

(also, check out the numerous questions about showing errors in php, so you'd catch that last syntax error, if that is really in your code.)